# Redux normalized state shape deleting reference Ids multiple places

Tags: redux

getting into redux world and just want to make sure If what I'm doing is sane and correct. Example we have normalized state that looks like this:

```

```
posts: {
      "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "My first post!",
        "author": "Jake",
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "This other other post",
        "author": "Paul",
      },
      "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "This new post",
        "author": "Billy",
      },
      "4": {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "This other other other post",
        "author": "Arnold",
      },
    },
globalFeed: {
  postIds:["1","2","3","4"]
},
myFeed: {
  postIds:["1","2"]
},
```

```

We have two different feeds, and have references to posts that contain them. I read Dan Abramov post somewhere about deleting items in normalized state, and he mentioned that deleting references to that item is good solution if it's a list.

But in my app, we can see a list of posts and see one post, so deleting just references is not a solution. So my question, if I just delete particular post (i.e. post with Id 1) from state and leave references intact. Then use selector to retrieve posts and filter undefined values. Is this solution sane ? Will I run into some problems ? Is there any better solution ? I Could delete particular post AND references, but if have multiple places that references that post, it's lot of boilerplate.

Selector example

```

```
const globalFeedPosts = state => {
  return state.globalFeed.postIds
        .map(id => state.posts[id])
        .filter(value => value !== undefined)
};
```

```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will definetly run into problems if you delete you post object from the resux store, In my opinion  a better approach would be to add one more flag in each of the post object which will allow to to filter the posts array as required somewath like below , hope this helps.

```
posts: {
      "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "My first post!",
        "author": "Jake",
        "isShown":true
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "This other other post",
        "author": "Paul",
        "isShown":false
      },
      "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "This new post",
        "author": "Billy",
        "isShown":false
      },
      "4": {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "This other other other post",
        "author": "Arnold",
        "isShown":false
      },
    },
globalFeed: {
  postIds:["1","2","3","4"]
},
myFeed: {
  postIds:["1","2"]
},
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what problems I can run into ? Just for educational purposes. Your solution sounds better, so selector would be same just instead of filter out posts that are undefined, filter posts that are "isShown":true,  yeah ? :)

Comment: yieah, absolutely. So moving on to the problems we will face is - Once the post object is removed from the store, we might be having the reference to it, but we will never be able to get back the original post object, we will lose the content of that object, and in case to make it available again we have to make a redundant copy of it before deleting it, because, if we try to add it back again, we need it . Hope this helps. sorry for the length of comment

Comment: One more thing, why would we need to add it back again ? If its deleted on server, we will never get it back :), or it's for undo/redo functionality ?

Comment: it was for undo/redo, if deleted on server, then nothing to worry about.